# Op-amp tutorial for electronic noobs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, tutorial

Can anyone point me to a tutorial for electronic noobs that 
explains how to use op-amps and what I can do with them, besides
amplification?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hyperphysics has a pretty good section about opamps:

- [Operational Amplifier Concepts](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/opampcon.html)
- [Op-amp Varieties](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/opampvar.html)

Comment: +1 This is a great link... a definitive list of everything you can do with an op amp. Thanks.

Comment: Hyperphysics in general is made of multiple flavors of win, with a sprinkling of awesome and a dash of genius. Between that and wikipedia the first 2 years of college are pretty much covered.

Comment: First two years of college except the sex.

Comment: @JoeStavitsky: Is there an overview/index page of Hyperphysics somewhere except the directory listing?

Answer (score 13):

I know it's not all online, but [the Art of Electronic by Horowitz and Hill](http://books.google.com/books?id=bkOMDgwFA28C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs%5Fnavlinks%5Fs#v=onepage&q=&f=false) is fantastic. It's basically the only book you need for the first 2 years of learning electronics (especially if you don't have any math requirements). The second edition of the book was published back in the late 80s and a lot of the example circuits using op amps are spectacular examples.

Comment: Horowitz and Hill not Howe

Comment: As someone in "the first two years of learning electronics", I must say that it's not necessarily for beginners. Some people may grasp it intuitively, but for the rest of us it's a concise reference.

Answer (score 7):

Try [Opamps for Everyone](http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/slod006b/slod006b.pdf)  (warning -- large pdf, and some TI bias)

It has lots to teach, covers beginning to somewhat advanced topics, and it's free.

Comment: Note that the section on noise calculation is full of errors, so be careful with this book.  The author no longer works for TI, though, so the latest edition is supposed to be unbiased.  http://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers/etc_amplifiers__other_linear/f/18/t/156728.aspx

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of very good tutorials at Analog Devices and Texas Instruments.
The TI one is called "[Handbook of Operational Amplifiers](http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/sboa092a/sboa092a.pdf)".

Answer (score 4):

[Op amp Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0138896011)

This book is considered to be a key text on the subject.  I dont think there is an online version available... £30 (where I come from) is around the "reasonable" price range for such books.

Comment: I will add my vote.  It can be found on abebooks as well.  Excellent book, covers how to do all manner of analog math with op-amps.  Linearization, converting linear to logarithmic, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Falstad  [Falstad Circuit index](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-index.html) has an excellent Java applet that allows you to do virtual prototyping with various types of circuits.

Has a nice section on **Op amps**, whats great is the built in O'scope, volt and current meters. Right clicking on a template component in the applet brings up menu where you can experiment/substitute with different values, add remove components.

Comment: I've just discovered this app. It's great !

Answer (score 3):

Check out: http://www.opencircuits.com/Op_amp

Answer (score 2):

This one helped me a lot for a Devices class which included op-amps. Really good animations, and covers most types (inverter, differentiator...) needed for a starting point.[link text]

http://electronics.wisc-online.com/Search.asp?search=op+amp

[1]

Answer (score 2):

I always simulate my op amp and other analogue circuits with SPICE before building and testing them. Free SPICE implementations are available, and many PCB packages include it.

Comment: It's no use simulating if you don't know how to use them.

Comment: Why the downvote? It helps one learn how to use them without wasting time building hardware that doesn't work. SPICE packages generally have plenty of examples of op amp circuits.

Answer (score 0):

[**Op Amps for Everyone**](http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/slod006b/slod006b.pdf) (2.0 MB PDF) by Texas Instruments is a very good reference.
It covers almost any aspect you might need. Even single supply opamp techniques.

Comment: Duplicate of [[this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/596/142)

Answer (score 0):

The "IC Opamp Cookbook" paperback was ~THE~ standard for hobbyist electronics back in the 80s.  Still a good reference.